# I have this code and it returns this error

Tags: node.js, ejs

This is my code:

```
        <% if(errors){ %>
            <% errors.forEach(e => { %>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <%= e.msg %>
                </div>
            <% }); $>
        <% }; %>
```

I have it under one of my h2 tags and before anyone asks, yes I did pass the paramter of errors.
Now time for the error

```
Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%".
at C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:693:19
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Template.generateSource (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:678:15)
at Template.compile (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:557:12)
at Object.compile (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:389:16)
at handleCache (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:212:18)
at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:16)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
at View.render (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
at C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\routes\main.js:59:17
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\dylda\Desktop\server_helper\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
```

All my other tags are closed as when I get rid of this the error goes too.

Thanks for all help in advance

Comment: in your penultimate line, the tag is not closed

Comment: In the title, please be more specific about the error. <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic">Check the on/off topic wiki.</a> Specifically: `Please be specific`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the error you're getting you'll notice it says ***Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%"***.

If you look at the code you provided, you'll notice that there is not a matching, closing "`<%`" tag.

This should fix it up:

```
        <% if(errors){ %>
        <% errors.forEach(e => { %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <%= e.msg %>
            </div>
        <% }); %>  // Notice change here
    <% }; %>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the penultimate line, you wrote `$>` instead of `%>`

```
<% if(errors){ %>
        <% errors.forEach(e => { %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <%= e.msg %>
            </div>
        <% }); %> // this line has a $>, instead of %>
    <% }; %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ejs2 file, you should use `<$ $>`, `<% %>`, `<? ?>` and `<@ @>`
So you must use one of them.

```
<$ %>, `<@ ?>`
```

Considered as an error